# Ionic 2 - Get data back from modal

Tags: ionic2

I have a component which is my main interface. Inside this component, clicking a button opens ionic 2 modal which allows to choose items.

My modal page (itemsPage):

```
..list of items here

    <button ion-button [disabled]="!MY_TURN || !selectedItem || !selectedItem.quantity"
       (click)="useItem(selectedItem)">
        <span>Choose item {{selectedItem?.name}}</span>
      </button>
```

`useItem()` should:

- Send item data to my main interface component
- Close the modal
- Execute a method in my main interface

How I can perform such actions? Couldn't find any documentation about communicating between modal and component in Ionic 2.

Comment: Sending data from modal to component is not support in ionic 2. I use some hidden part in my page instead.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It is simply a matter of using parameters in `viewController`.

In your main interface component,

```
let chooseModal = this.modalCtrl.create(itemsPage);
  chooseModal.onDidDismiss(data => {
     console.log(data);
});
chooseModal.present();
```

In your modal page,

```
useItem(item) {   
  this.viewCtrl.dismiss(item);
}
```

Modal Controller link [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/modal/ModalController/)

Comment: `ViewController` was removed in v4, use `ModalController` for dismissing instead.

Answer (score 4):

This is a clear example of getting data from modals in ionic.
You need to add a handler for modal’s onDismiss() and then return the data from the modal itself by passing the data to the ViewController’s dismiss() method:

```
// myPage.ts
// Passing data to the modal:
let modal = Modal.create(myModal, { data: [...] });

// Getting data from the modal:
modal.onDismiss(data => {
  console.log('MODAL DATA', data);
 });

this.nav.present(modal);
```

on the modal page

```
// myModal.ts
constructor(private navParams: NavParams, private viewCtrl: ViewController) {
// Getting data from the page:
  var dataFromPage = navParams.get('data');
}

dismiss() {
// Returning data from the modal:
  this.viewCtrl.dismiss(
      // Whatever should be returned, e.g. a variable name:
      // { name : this.name } 
  );
}
```

Comment: it says "onDismiss" is not a function