# Ionic 4 - Pass Data BACK from Modal

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to create a modal window, pass it an array of objects, have a user select one object from that array, and then have my modal pass back the object they've selected.

I've tried using the Ionic 2 approach of modalName.onDidDismiss(data=> …) [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41521251/ionic-2-get-data-back-from-modal), but apparently Ionic 4 changed "onDidDismiss" to not accept any values passed back to it.

So I'm at a loss for how to send data from my Modal window back to the page that called it.

Comment: Ionic 4's documentation need much more work before it is good enough to start messing with it. I tried it for a week and gave up after finding the alerters examples incredibly non intuitive to initialize and use.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Some days ago I had the same problem and here's my solution:

I guess, you already have a component which contains the actual modal. name `UserModalComponent`

Your `UserModalComponent` should get the ModalController injected:

Next step is to pass the selected user back:

```
selectUser(user: User):void {
  this.modalController.dismiss(user);
}
```

In your component in which you want to call the modal and get the user back, you also have to inject the `ModalController` as above and additionally, you need this method:

```
 async openUserModal() {
    const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: UserModalComponent,
      componentProps: { users: this.users },
    });

    modal.onDidDismiss()
      .then((data) => {
        const user = data['data']; // Here's your selected user!
    });

    return await modal.present();
  }
```

If anything is unclear, just ask!

Comment: You are a saint. This is exactly what I needed - I hadn't thought to use ".then()" to handle the returned data. Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you know how to differentiate when a component was opened my a modal controller or a router navigation in order to dismiss the component according to it?

Comment: I would just pass different componentProps to the modal

Comment: Your way is working! But in the doc its written like this 
<code> 
    `const modal = await modalController.create({...});
    const { data } = await modal.onDidDismiss();
    console.log(data);`
</code>
But when I used the same its not working, why?

Comment: What's up with the first code snipped being empty?  Bad edit?

Answer (score 5):

This is how you get data back from modal in Ionic 4 :

```
contactsModal.onDidDismiss().then(data => {
    console.log('data came back from modal');
    console.log(data);
})
```