# When using the new ModalController in Ionic 5, is it possible to pass data back when a swipeToClose or backdropDismiss is triggered?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, modal-dialog

Using Ionic 5's new ModalController, in addition to the backdropDismiss parameter, it is also now possible to set a new parameter which enables the user to swipe a modal down to close it like so:

```
const modal = await this.modalController.create({
  component: ModalPage,
  backdropDismiss: true, // <-- enable backdrop dismiss
  swipeToClose: true, // <-- enable swipe to close
  presentingElement: await this.modalController.getTop()
});
return await modal.present();
```

Specific to when a user triggers a `swipeToClose` or `backdropDismiss`, Is it possible to pass data back to the `onWillDismiss()` or `onDidDismiss()` events?

I am aware of the `dismiss()` method which allows us to pass data back to the origin component programmatically. That method does **not** address how to pass data back when the `swipeToClose` or `backdropDismiss` events are fired.

It may be the case that this is simply not possible, to which i can come up with a workaround, but thought id propose the question here first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ionic 4 - Pass Data BACK from Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52785797/ionic-4-pass-data-back-from-modal)

Comment: Unfortunately no. That page shows how to pass data back by dismissing the modal programmatically. I am talking about a need for setting data that will be passed automatically to the origin component via the swipeToClose and / or backdropDismiss events.

Comment: According to the Documentation `onWillDismiss()` or `onDidDismiss()` events should work with `backdropDismiss` and `swipeToClose`

Comment: Thanks @NajamUsSaqib yes they do execute, however, what i was looking for was to find out if there was a property i could set in the modal component that would be passed by default to those event methods, however, it does not look like that is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I today run into the Same Question and found a Solution:

Let's say you have your **Page**, where you open the Modal:

```
this.modalController.create({
  component: ModalPage,
  backdropDismiss: true, // <-- enable backdrop dismiss
  swipeToClose: true, // <-- enable swipe to close
  presentingElement: await this.modalController.getTop()
}).then(modal => {
  modal.onWillDismiss().then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
  modal.present();
});
```

And then you have your **ModalPage**. An Ionic Overlay automatically includes the Overlay into itself, so if just include `private modal: HTMLIonModalElement;` into the Modal, it will be available and you can do something like this in the **OnInit**:

```
this.modal.onWillDismiss().then(data => {
  data.data = 'test';
});
```

This will be executed before the one from your main Page and you can change the data and role here